# Python multiprocessing starmap_async is not terminating?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I'm trying out the `starmap_async` method to test out multi-processing with multiple arguments, and I literally have just this running in my Jupyter notebook:

```py
import multiprocessing

def test_async(i, j, k, l):
    print(i, j, k, l)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    result = pool.starmap_async(test_async, [(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 7, 8)])
    result.get()
```

This cell never terminates, it's always in * state. When I force terminate it, I get the error

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-70185b68aa7c> in <module>
      4 with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
      5     result = pool.starmap_async(test_async, [(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7)])
----> 6     result.get()
      7     pool.join()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    763 
    764     def get(self, timeout=None):
--> 765         self.wait(timeout)
    766         if not self.ready():
    767             raise TimeoutError

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in wait(self, timeout)
    760 
    761     def wait(self, timeout=None):
--> 762         self._event.wait(timeout)
    763 
    764     def get(self, timeout=None):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    556             signaled = self._flag
    557             if not signaled:
--> 558                 signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
    559             return signaled
    560 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    300         try:    # restore state no matter what (e.g., KeyboardInterrupt)
    301             if timeout is None:
--> 302                 waiter.acquire()
    303                 gotit = True
    304             else:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Am I missing something?

Update: So I'm actually aware of the `.close()` and `.join()` issues and I've tried all possible combinations, including omitting the two functions altogether and it does not change anything. I'm looking for a Jupyter-specific solution.

Comment: You need to call close before join (see [`pool.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join)) but since this is inside a with block, you don't either close or join. Remove the close and it works on my linux machine on the command line. I don't know the jupyter side of things.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate issue already reported on SO; I just couldn't readily find it. Anyway, the solution is to place function `test_async` in a module, for example, **worker.py** and then:

```py
import multiprocessing
from worker import test_async

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        result = pool.starmap_async(test_async, [(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 7, 8)])
        result.get()
        # pool.join() # cannot call this without first calling pool.close()
```

If **worker.py** is in the same directory as the notebook file containing this cell, for example, then `worker.py` by definition will be in a directory on the module search path.

By the way, your code is equivalent to:

```py
import multiprocessing
from worker import test_async

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.starmap(test_async, [(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 7, 8)])
```

There is no real need for `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` since you are waiting for all submitted tasks to complete anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are missing something.  Your "with" section must be inside

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

The documentation warns of this.  Remember, when you do a multiprocessing, each new process starts over from scratch and has to RELOAD your main file.  Unless you have the `__name__` check, it will start an infinite loop where each new process will spin off more processes.

Comment: I'm using a Jupyter notebook though. I don't think the name check works; it still hangs.

Comment: This is a problem when spawning instead of forking - its usually only seen on Windows. And multiprocessing tries to detect the problem and raise an error.

Comment: If you have fixed the code, show us the fixed code.